# How to match only written \n in string contain new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all written \n by \n
In javascript but the result is totally wrong
This my code

```
var a=`
\n
`;
a.replace(/\n/g,"\\n")
```

The result

```
"\\n\\n\\n"
```

And i expect

```
`
\\n
`
```

Comment: Do you mean `a.replace(/\\n/g,"\\n")`?

Comment: No, i need to replace written \n by \\n

Comment: written where? User input?

Comment: In varaible i have paragraph contain \n string

Comment: Look, template string literals still support escape sequences. You cannot differentiate a literal newline from a newline escape sequence once the string is compiled.

Comment: string and expected is a same?

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you to match your expected output. I am not completely understanding the situation though.

```
a.replace(/\\n/g,"\\\\n")
```